# How to fix the error Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;?

Tags: android, dex

I constantly get following two errors:

```
[2012-12-09 21:39:50 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;
[2012-12-09 21:39:50 - TimeTable] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gcm/GCMBaseIntentService;
```

I am new to Android so I didn't succeed it on my own.

Comment: You should post the code which throws this two errors, without that it will be hard to give you any help.

Comment: I don't get a line number with the error. It occurs when I try to run the app or try to export it to an apk.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project? In eclipse click on project -> Clean. It sounds like you have duplicate libraries (or duplicate somethings). Check your libs folder and build path.

Comment: My libs map is empty. Every library is placed under the map Referenced Libraries. And everytime I try to export the app, eclipse or somehow everytimes a new Android Dependencies is created in the build path window

Comment: Also when I clean the project he automaticly creates Android Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My error was that I used the same class name in the same package name the same like I was using in a Library in my project. When I remove this class and just used the one in the library everything worked fine.
so try to remove the library or try to exclude the class "GCMBaseIntentService" from build path.
hope that will help u